# Select other buttons on touch move

Tags: android, touch, selector, android-custom-view

I'm writing a test which options are placed in buttons. I have a selector for buttons that displays normal and pressed state and everything works great.
What i want is that when user touches an option and moves to next option, the next button get focus and select. And when user takes the hand, perform the selected button click.

[image: user touch one of options]
[image: user moves to next option]

In images above you can see exactly what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom touch event management that will trigger `setPressed(true)` on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` **OR** `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` (the default implementation expects to always receive `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`).

Code like this should work (add it to all your buttons):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!v.isPressed()) {
                    v.setPressed(true);
                }
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // perform action ON CLICK
                break;
        }

        v.setPressed(false);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this solution not working because when touch moves, this is just for the button that user start from there and other buttons won't response to it.

Comment: have you even tried it? The important part is that when the finger crosses the boundary of a button touch area `MotionEvent.Action_CANCEL` should be called on this button, and then in the example I provided onTouch listener will return **false**. Due to that the touch event management will be handed over to other components.

Comment: yes i tried it. the problem is that MotionEvent.Action_CANCEL not called when touch left the button. actually cancel never called in touch, i logged it and i don't know why.

Comment: Are those buttons stored in some sort of `ScrollView`?

Comment: Well I would have to check the code to find the real reason why the event is not being called then... The other approach you can take is to add a `onTouchEvent` listener to your LinearLayout instead to your buttons. Inside this listener, if MOVE or DOWN event is triggered, you find a proper `View` for this event (based on coordinates of touch event), set its pressed state to `true`, and for all the other ones pressed state to `false`. When `MotionEvent.Action_UP` is detected, perfom "on click action" for the proper `View`.

Comment: yes this is the true answer that i worked on it about 3 hours and fixed it. the purpose of this question was that to ask if any easier solution exists. thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Is here any soulution for this ?